# Deploy error ruby on rails Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to run on Digitalocean

```
cap production deploy
```

but i got this this error

> ```
> 00:42 deploy:assets:precompile
> 01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
> 01 rake aborted!
> 01 Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile' (See the list of available tasks with rake -… 01
> ```
>
> /home/deploy/RubyProject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in
> <top (requi…
> 01 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in load' 01 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/bin/bundle:23:in
> '
> 01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)

when i try

```
rake --tasks
```

i don't find assets:precompile

> ```
> rake about # List versions of all Rails frameworks and the environment
> rake action_mailbox:ingress:exim # Relay an inbound email from Exim to Action Mailbox (URL and ...
> rake action_mailbox:ingress:postfix # Relay an inbound email from Postfix to Action Mailbox (URL a...
> rake action_mailbox:ingress:qmail # Relay an inbound email from Qmail to Action Mailbox (URL and...
> rake action_mailbox:install # Copy over the migration
> rake action_text:install # Copy over the migration, stylesheet, and JavaScript files
> rake active_storage:install # Copy over the migration needed to the application
> rake app:template # Applies the template supplied by LOCATION=(/path/to/template...
> rake app:update # Update configs and some other initially generated files (or ...
> rake db:create # Creates the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.ym...
> rake db:drop # Drops the database from DATABASE_URL or config/database.yml ...
> rake db:environment:set # Set the environment value for the database
> rake db:fixtures:load # Loads fixtures into the current environment's database
> rake db:migrate # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false, SCO...
> rake db:migrate:status # Display status of migrations
> rake db:prepare # Runs setup if database does not exist, or runs migrations if...
> rake db:rollback # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps...
> rake db:schema:cache:clear # Clears a db/schema_cache.yml file
> rake db:schema:cache:dump # Creates a db/schema_cache.yml file
> rake db:schema:dump # Creates a db/schema.rb file that is portable against any DB ...
> rake db:schema:load # Loads a schema.rb file into the database
> rake db:seed # Loads the seed data from db/seeds.rb
> rake db:seed:replant # Truncates tables of each database for current environment an...
> rake db:setup # Creates the database, loads the schema, and initializes with...
> rake db:structure:dump # Dumps the database structure to db/structure.sql
> rake db:structure:load # Recreates the databases from the structure.sql file
> rake db:version # Retrieves the current schema version number
> rake log:clear # Truncates all/specified *.log files in log/ to zero bytes (s...
> rake middleware # Prints out your Rack middleware stack
> rake restart # Restart app by touching tmp/restart.txt
> rake secret # Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typi...
> rake stats # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc) from the application or ...
> rake test # Runs all tests in test folder except system ones
> rake test:db # Run tests quickly, but also reset db
> rake test:system # Run system tests only
> rake time:zones[country_or_offset] # List all time zones, list by two-letter country code (`rails...
> rake tmp:clear # Clear cache, socket and screenshot files from tmp/ (narrow w...
> rake tmp:create # Creates tmp directories for cache, sockets, and pids
> rake yarn:install # Install all JavaScript dependencies as specified via Yarn
> rake zeitwerk:check # Checks project structure for Zeitwerk compatibility
> ```

System configuration

Rails version: 6.0.3.3

Ruby version: 2.6.6

Someone can help me thanks.

Comment: I found the same issue. But my rake is 13.0.3
```deployment@testdeploy:/var/www/testdeploy/code$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)```

Comment: see the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052204/deploy-raise-error-dont-know-how-to-build-task-assetsprecompile-capistran)