# Rails 6 Capistrano error "assets:precompile"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-6

Please, I have the same problem: [Deploy error ruby on rails Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64231191/8478892)

If it's possible, helpme and help this guy too.

Thanks in advance for your attention

**Update:**

With @Anuj help, I find the solution:
Precisely because my project is API by default, I don't have the precompile assets (@Anuj said the same, I didn't know).
The solution to me is:

**->** remove inside my Capfile: `require 'capistrano/rails/assets'`

**->** remove inside my deploy.rb `after  :finishing,    :compile_assets`

Comment: Do you have an API only application?

Comment: @Anuj yes! Only api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assets:precompile` is a task provided by [Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets), which does not get included by default in an API only app (because APIs don't need assets).

In your Capfile, when you write

```
require 'capistrano/rails'
```

it basically includes both the below lines automatically

```
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

If you replace the `capistrano/rails` with just `capistrano/rails/migrations` in your Capfile, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand what you told me about the API. However, I added what you say into my Capfile, but the error keeps showing up: ```deploy:assets:precompile                                                                                                                                                                                           01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile                                                                                                                                                  01 rake aborted!```

Comment: But, I find the solution because this and I edit my ask. So, I mark your reply with accepted. Thanks for your help @Anuj. And If is possible, I have another most difficult question about the PUMA: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65492028/8478892